# PHP: Is this the correct way of using a function that is defined under a class?

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I have a PHP class inside my Wordpress plugin that is activated in a website. I want to use a method (doc_export function) that is defined inside this class in another plugins (also activated in the same website). I add this one and it seems working:

```
<?php
        // Export doc
        if (defined('DOC_ADMIN_MODE')) {

            $my_Documentation = new Class_Documentation;
            $mydocexport = $my_Documentation->doc_export();
            $mydocexport_file = ABSPATH . '_export/' . basename($site['site_url']) . '/doc.xml';
            file_put_contents($mydocexport_file, $mydocexport);
        }
?>
```

I want to know if this is the proper approach..Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's the proper approach. You can also read about the OOP basis in PHP at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php